Can I use WD SATA 1 TB Desktop Internal Hard Disk Drive (WD10EZEX) with my Orico 3.5 Inch Hard Disk Enclosure?
I am using an M1 MacBook Pro and I want to create a proper offline backup of my machine. I use cloud services (including storage) almost exclusively and regularly clean my computer so I have less than 250 GB of data on my computer.
I have a cheap Orico 3.5 inch Hard Disk enclosure which I never used before.
It outputs in USB 3.0 Type-A. I plan to buy an adapter then connect the Orico enclosure to my laptop.
Will this part cause any issues? What will be the impact of using a cheap adapter here?
Secondly, I am looking into buying a good long-term HDD or SSD and due to a good balance of pricing and reputation I am currently thinking of buying the WD SATA 1 TB Desktop Internal Hard Disk Drive (WD10EZEX).
Will it work perfectly with the Orico enclosure I have?
Lastly, if you could guide me, according to the Amazon description, the enclosure can fit both 2.5 and 3.5. SSDs and HDDs, but it is not mentioned anywhere on the official box. As it is SATA 3, do you think that
I can even use an SSD in this system I am trying to create?
Something like Western Digital WD Blue SA510?

An SSD would be better. I suggest you get the Crucial P3 Plus then get an SSD enclosure. It's a good budget SSD with pretty good reliability as well.
